# If $x^n+y^n=a^n$, what is dy/dx?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have done the math and my answer is $-(x/y)^{n-1}$. But I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Next time, it would be good if you included your working in the question. Questions that don't include evidence of your attempts to solve the problem typically end up closed, deleted, and tend to be voted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see.   $x^n+y^n=a^n\implies nx^{n-1}+ny^{n-1}\frac{\operatorname{dy}}{\operatorname {dx}}=0\implies\boxed{\frac{\operatorname{dy}}{\operatorname {dx}}=-(\frac xy)^{n-1}}$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^n+y^n=a^n$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^n+y^n\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[a^n\right]$$
$$nx^{n-1}+ny^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-nx^{n-1}}{ny^{n-1}}=\frac{-x^{n-1}}{(a^n-x^n)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}$$